# Runnig old Android Project on Android Studio gives "mapper not supported" and "ioctl failed with code -1: Invalid argument" error

Tags: android, android-studio, ioctl

I am trying to run old Android project on a mobile device using Android Studio. (Project version: `compileSdkVersion 23, buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'`) When I run the project on Android Studio it gives following error

```
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
```

Debug log

```
10/24 18:37:06: Launching 'app' on xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.vihanga.myApp/com.vihanga.myApp.Test" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.vihanga.myApp.test | com.vihanga.myApp
Waiting for application to come online: com.vihanga.myApp.test | com.vihanga.myApp
Connected to process 30696 on device 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/ActivityThread: Application com.vihanga.myApp is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
Waiting for application to come online: com.vihanga.myApp.test | com.vihanga.myApp
Connecting to com.vihanga.myApp
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/ActivityThread: Application com.vihanga.myApp is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8602', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/chatty: uid=10199(com.vihanga.myApp) identical 1 line
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1413)
I/SurfaceFactory: [static] sSurfaceFactory = com.mediatek.view.impl.SurfaceFactoryImpl@a24bc74
D/ViewRootImpl[Test]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@f0b2be0, this = DecorView@e601e99[Test]
I/GPUD: @gpudInitialize: successfully initialized with GL, dbg=0 mmdump_dbg=0 mmpath_dbg=0
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x969e8800,api=1)
D/Surface: Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x969e8800,bufferCount=3)
D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x969e8800)
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=792ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=93008939501104, Vsync=93008973871268, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=93008979759065, AnimationStart=93008980716603, PerformTraversalsStart=93008980816757, DrawStart=93009551430526, SyncQueued=93009671538219, SyncStart=93009687115372, IssueDrawCommandsStart=93009687319834, SwapBuffers=93009745214065, FrameCompleted=93009747636526, DequeueBufferDuration=0, QueueBufferDuration=1354000,
```

Any idea on this?